# Crop scanned document using Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a scanned document image  as below :

[image: Example of a scanned document]

I need to crop the document from the image.Can anyone tell me how to do with OpenCV .

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/).

Answer (score 0):

In very clear samples like the one you provided:

1. To Gray
2. Canny
3. FindContours
4. Find biggest contour

However, this method will not work for 99% of samples.
If you have more samples, add them to your post please.